# How to recognize search patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, vb.net

I am working on a project where I want to implement functionality where system will remember users choice on basis of his last search or activity (like Facebook and Google).

Not able to understand how to start on this. Please suggest some good ideas.

P.S : I am using vb.net, Javascript, jQuery, AngularJs, SQL Server 2008

Comment: you may want to use 'cookies'

Comment: I want to explore options better than cookies..please suggest something other than cookie

Answer (score 1):

Other than cookies, you can try Session.
If HTML5 compliant browser then you can even have client side database. 
You can also use local/session storage of HTML5. There is something called jStorage. Check that out.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on client side data..thanks in advance :)

Comment: kindly have a look at these links http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/index.html  ,also this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/ .You may find this helpful